# In clojure, why does a block comment containing a url throw an exception?

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

Why does the following is not work? That is why does it throw an exception?:

```
(comment 

Replicate a Sequence
http://www.4clojure.com/problem/33

        (= (__ [1 2 3] 2) '(1 1 2 2 3 3))

)
```

Replace the url with another string and it seems to be ok.

```
(comment 

Replicate a Sequence
replace the url and all is well. why 

        (= (__ [1 2 3] 2) '(1 1 2 2 3 3))

)
```

Comment: it's the combination of `:/` in the URL. Both characters have special meaning in clojure, but not sure why they wouldn't work in the comment macro.

Comment: @Kevin because the bodies of macros still have to be parsed, even if they're not evaluated.  The url doesn't parse.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the url is not a valid token:

```
Clojure> http://www.4clojure.com/problem/33
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid token: http://www.4clojure.com/problem/33
```

Whereas the other string you had *can* be read as Clojure forms:

```
Clojure> (quote (replace the url and all is well. why))
(replace the url and all is well. why)
```

That is, Clojure can't parse the first example, regardless of whether it's in a `(comment ...)`.

For completeness, note that the url is fine with a `;` comment:

```
Clojure> 3 ; http://www.4clojure.com/problem/33
3
```

Comment: am I better off always using ';' for comments as 'comment'  macro (what I learnt from you) evaluates its contents?

Comment: @user193116 `comment` doesn't **evaluate** its body -- although its body is **parsed**.  I personally always use `;` for comments, because it's more visually distinctive (and now also because of the problem you found).  I'd only use `comment` if I were in a hurry or lazy.  I worked with a guy once who never deleted code, just put `(comment ...)` around it -- made it very hard to read the code. ... but that's just personal taste.  YMMV.

Comment: For completeness, it's worth noting the `#_` reader syntax instructs the reader to not parse the following form.

Comment: @Huw This is incorrect. You say it yourself: "the following form." So the form following `#_` must legal code just as for the `comment` macro. The difference between the two is that `comment` is a macro and as such has to produce something, namely a `nil`. With `#_` the form just vanishes. Schameless plug: ["Did you know about comments?"](http://kotka.de/blog/2010/06/Did_you_know_V.html)